# How should c# references be handled when working with DevOps artifacts?

Tags: azure-devops

I am new to DevOps. I will explain my structure first.

```
Project 1>
    Repo 1
    Repo 2
```

I am trying to make two build pipelines one that will build Repo 1 and a second that will build repo 2.

Repo 2 has a dependency on Repo1.dll.

I understand that I can publish the Repo1.dll and then download the artifact in repo2's pipeline.

My trouble is, our developers normal workflow is to have both repo's running in debug on their machines using a project reference. I am having trouble understanding how to reference Repo 1 from Repo 2 in a way that the artifact can be used in DevOps and project reference can be used on the developers machines.

Comment: Why do you have a direct dependency on a DLL from another repo? If you're going to share a library across other repos, then use the standard way of sharing libraries in .NET: create a NuGet package. Azure DevOps even provides NuGet feed hosting for you.

Comment: Sounds like they should be using package references, not project references, by using some form of internal NuGet feed

Comment: Unless it's particularly complicated, I'd just put both projects in the same repo.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking you're using [Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/)? If so, then you need to fix the tag on your question. "devops" is a concept, whereas Azure DevOps is a specific product, for which you should use this [azure-devops](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/azure-devops/info) tag.

Comment: Would the developer need to build and push the change made to Repo1.sln and then Restore that change on Repo2.sln to debug?

Comment: Assuming you go the NuGet approach rather than DavidG's approach, then you would have to build the NuGet package, publish it to the feed, then in the consuming app you'd update your package references to refer to the package you just pushed. If you're trying to decide what approach you use, you need to consider how interconnected the different .NET projects are. Do you really need two different repos? Should they maybe be .NET projects in the same solution in the same repo? Will they need to be deployed separately? These are the kinds of things you need to think about.

Answer (score 0):

> How should c# references be handled when working with DevOps artifacts?

The best way to do this is using the NuGet.

When you build Repo 1 and create the nuget package `Package1`. Then publish this package `Package1` to the Azure devops feed.

Now, add this package `Package1` to the `solution2` in the Visual Studio from the feed.

When we update the `repo1`, we need to build the NuGet package, publish it to the feed, then update the refernces package version to refer to the package you just publish.